# When every point of a topological dynamical system is recurrent.

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

## Definitions

A **topological dynamical system** is a pair $(X, T)$ where $X$ is a compact metric space and let $T:X\to X$ is a continuous map.

By the **forward-orbit** of a point $x$ in $X$ we mean the set $O_x=\{T^nx:\ n=1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

We say that a point $x$ in $X$ is **generic** if $\bar O_x$ (closure of $O_x$) is $X$.

We say that $x$ is **recurrent** if

$$x\in \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\overline{\{T^ix:\ i\geq n\}}$$
(Thanks to @JohnB for correcting the definition of a recurrent point).

We say that the dynamical system $(X, T)$ is **minimal** if the only non-empty $T$-invariant closed subset of $X$ is $X$.

## Question.

It is easy to show that if $(X, T)$ is a minimal system then every point of $X$ is generic and hence every point is recurrent.

Suppose $(X, T)$ is such that every point is recurrent. This is not enough to ensure minimality. For one can consider the closed disc $D^2$ with an irrational rotation.

So I am wondering if the following is true:

> Let $(X, T)$ be a topological dynamical system such that every point of $X$ is recurrent and that there is at least one generic point. Does this imply that the system is minimal? What if one assumes $T$ is a homeomorphism and not just a continuous map?

Comment: Given that topological dynamical systems is included into the tag [dynamical-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamical-systems/info), is it really necessary to introduce the new tag "topological-dynamics"?

Comment: The tag 'dynamical-systems' did not come to my mind.

Comment: Your notion "We say that $x$ is **recurrent** if $x\in \bar O_x$." is not the usual one in terms of $\omega$-limit sets.

Comment: @JohnB You are right. My thinking was cloudy. I have edited.

Comment: following paper might be relevant, sounds there might be example http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm6/cm618.pdf more links https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6a37/77f33eb574ee07441ae8d7373f8938984b12.pdf | https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4899-6696-4_6 | https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f8ab/9ccf79af7699064308af32d4bc5cc6c6afe6.pdf | https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1181068757 | https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1181072815 | https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.2728.pdf | https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/97b2/8086bf5d790210d1fd28163f043c9aa4ea1e.pdf

Comment: @Mirko That is some crazy reference hunting skills! The links seem very interesting and relevant. Thanks!